# Java JEditorPane: detecting failure to connect to site

Tags: java, html, browser, jeditorpane

I'm using a JEditorPane as a web browser, and I need to be able to detect any failure to load the page of a properly formatted URL (i.e. doesn't throw `MalformedURLException`). I use PropertyChangeListener (with property name "page") for when a page has finished loading, but it does nothing when I enter some random gibberish like `http://geowfkwpf.com/`, and neither does any other listener that can be applied to JEditorPane (I tried them all).

Edit: also, there's a "plong" sound effect about 2 seconds after I enter the link, presumably when the program has concluded that it cannot connect, so there must be some way of "listening" (ha) to it. By the way, if there's a way to disable that sound please let me know, but that's a tertiary concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The line `myJEditorPane.setContentType("text/html");` (it's `"text/plain"` by default) causes `myJEditorPane.setPage(url)` to not throw `UnknownHostException` but instead make the "plong" sound. I don't know why, I don't know how you solve the problem if you need to set the content type to html, and I don't know what setting the content type to html does, but hey, I solved the problem for me.